# In a fresh install of kubuntu, I cannot install programs from discover, and I cannot update from the command line

Tags: package-management, 18.04, kubuntu, dependencies

I'm asked for my password. I enter it and it says installing, but then I get the message that it failed to install, and installing becomes install again. I tried to update from the command line and I got the message that I ought to run `--fix-broken installation`, which I did, and I got the following output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139

Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While I don't understand most of that, I get the feeling that this is not a healthy installation. I would burn another DVD and start over, but I have no burning software. So let this be a cautionary tale: have extra backups before you wipe out your system. Does anyone know how an installation could get mess up like this? The DVD I installed from is clean with no visible defects.

The DVD is one I've used successfully before, so I know it's okay. I just tried to update with apt with the following result:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>". See "man sudo_root" for details.   
billie@arachne:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y 
[sudo] password for billie:  
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB] 
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB] 
Fetched 247 kB in 11s (23.4 kB/s)                            
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 2
78 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them. 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 abiword : Depends: libabiword-3.0 (>= 3.0.2) but it is not installed  abiword-plugin-grammar : Depends: libabiword-3.0 (>= 3.0.2) but it is not installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). 
billie@arachne:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed:   
libabiword-3.0 The following NEW packages will be installed: libabiword-3.0 
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 278 not upgraded. 23 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/1,995 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 7,737 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Setting up base-files (10.1ubuntu2.1) ... 
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue ... 
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue.net ... 
Installing new version of config file /etc/lsb-release ... 
motd-news.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it. 
(Reading database ... 262286 files and directories currently installed.)    
Preparing to unpack .../libabiword-3.0_3.0.2-6_amd64.deb ...   
Unpacking libabiword-3.0:amd64 (3.0.2-6) ... 
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error:
 compressed data is corrupt dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libabiword-3.0_3.0.2-6_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libabiword-3.0.so' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libabiword-3.0.so.dpkg-new':
 unexpected end of file or stream Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libabiword-3.0_3.0.2-6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)   
billie@arachne:~$
```

I am completely lost. I've never encountered a situation like this. btw, I reinstalled and have the same problem.

Comment: There may be a gui way, but I'm not a gui person. My suggestion is to grab the name of the software (let's say it was `leafpad` (an lxde text editor), I would close the gui app, open a terminal and enter the command to install it.  `sudo apt-get install leafpad`.  The terminal provides a lot more information, and if it fails to install you'll get errors & probably a recommended (eg. 'suggest you run sudo apt-get -f install; etc). It also gives you errors you can post here so we can provide advice & better help.  Possibly worth running `sudo apt-get update` first anyway, and Kubuntu version?

Comment: `dpkg` is the main program that handles .deb packages used by the system, and some of its 'tooling' uses python code; so with a broken python system, your package management tools may not work & will give you troubles. This is what you're discovering, but it doesn't mean the rest of your system is corrupt. The quickest fix may be re-installation as installing & removing packages without package-management-tools will be a pain.  Did you verify the ISO before you wrote it to dvd?  (even a single bit can corrupt one part of your system). I also 'try ubuntu' quite a while to test media as well...